# HTTP 404 with Nodejs app on ubuntu 18.04 AWS server running Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have moved my Nodejs (10.16) app to AWS ubuntu 18.04 running Nginx (17.4) reverse proxy from development after full testing. The problem I have is that there is http 404 to front end React Native request. Here is the log output on my front end:

```
[12:50:39] I | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'response in signup: ', { type: 'default',
                             │ status: 404,  //<<<=== Server Not Found
                             │ ok: false,
                             │ statusText: undefined,
                             │ headers:
                             │ { map:
                             │ { connection: 'keep-alive',
                             │ 'content-length': '153',
                             │ 'content-type': 'text/html',
                             │ date: 'Wed, 09 Oct 2019 19:50:40 GMT',
                             │ server: 'nginx/1.17.4' } },  //<<<=== Nginx 
                             │ url: 'http://my-aws-public-ip/api/users/signup', //<<<=== request URL
```

Here is the log output after starting app on the ubuntu server with `node index.js`:

```
Listening on port 3000...
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
DB connection has been established successfully.
```

Here the server is listening on port `3000` and database connection has been established successfully.

Here is the nginx proxy config file `default` under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`:

```
$cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Here is the `db.js` in nodejs app:

```
const Sql = require("sequelize");
const db = new Sql('emps', 'postgres', `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    port:5432,
} );

db
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('DB connection has been established successfully.');

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });

module.exports = db;
```

Here is the end of the index.js:

```
server.listen(port, () => {  //port=3000
  //logger('info', `Listening on port ${port}...`);
  console.log(`env var: ${process.env.jwtPrivateKey}`)
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`);

});
```

Here is the `routes.js`:

```
module.exports = function(app, io) {
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use('/api/events', events);
    app.use('/api/messages', messages);
    app.use('/api/users', users);
    app.use('/api/groups', groups);
    app.use('/api/contacts', contacts);
    app.use('/api/groupmembers', groupmembers);
    app.use('/api/sms', smsverif);
    app.use(error);
}
```

on AWS security group, inbound `TCP port 80, 22, 443 and 3000` are opened for all traffic. What is missing in the config causing http 404?

Comment: Can u show node server code snippet?

Comment: Some server code posted.

Comment: Could u post code handling api routes(requests)  which could  be useful to identify the issue?

Comment: Posted routes.js.

Comment: Everything looks fine. I used your nginx config locally in my systen and it worked.After the configuration have you reloaded or restarted nginx?

Comment: Also, were you able to hit API to http://aws-ip:3000/api/users/signup ? if so then the problem is with Nginx only else check with express(node) server

Comment: I removed port 3000 on my URL after deploying nodeapp to aws ubuntu. Let me see if i put the port 3000 back to URL.

Comment: Also I purged the nginx and reinstalled it.

Comment: `Sandeep Patel`, adding port 3000 back to URL made it working. Thank you. But I don't quite understand why I need use port:3000 after nginx reverse proxy is setup. The nginx server listening on port 80 should redirect to port 3000 for nodejs app by reverse proxy. The online post I read does not have port 3000 specified in URL and I just followed this example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200673/discussion-between-sandeep-patel-and-user938363).

Comment: That means the problem is with Nginx configuration only. Once that is figured out you can remove the port  from URL and also from security group

Answer (score 1):

try this config for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost your-aws-public-ip default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, there is missing a `include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*`. The reverse proxy config has to be included in nginx.conf first.